# How to Troubleshoot Progress Bar Issues in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, html5-video, video.js

In [This example](https://codepen.io/rmuktader/pen/GQMjXM)  I can move the progress bar in Chrome. But in [this example](https://codepen.io/rmuktader/pen/ZrXpRZ) I cannot move the progress bar in Chrome (it doesn't even load in Safari). The only difference between the two HTML files is the working example is loading the video from http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4 and the non-working one is loading from http://test.nrtsalespro.com/system/files/video_server/uploaded_videos/oceans.mp4

So, my best guess is the two different servers are serving the files differently. But how do I troubleshoot this? What server/directory settings could cause this?

```
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/6.6.3/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="658" height="395"
  poster="http://via.placeholder.com/658x395" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="http://test.nrtsalespro.com/system/files/video_server/uploaded_videos/oceans.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
      <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
    </p>
  </video>

  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/6.6.3/video.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Video.js's troubleshooting guide](http://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-troubleshooting.html#problems-when-hosting-media) would be a good place to start since it addresses this, although this particular issue is general to HTML5 video rather than to Video.js specifically.

The server must support byte range requests for html5 video playback to work. Otherwise browsers cannot seek outside the buffered range, hence the behaviour on Chrome. Safari takes the harder line of blocking playback altogether; they consider it better to make sure you realise there's a problem with the hosting immediately.